# Drawing a covering rect on mouseover on a svg

Tags: javascript, svg

I would like to mark an area is active by  highlighting it with a new rect. I do

```
function coverRect(el){
    var x=el.x.animVal.value;
    var y=el.y.animVal.value;
    var width=el.width.animVal.value;
    var height=el.height.animVal.value;
    var svg   = document.documentElement;
    var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;
    var rect = document.createElementNS(svgNS,'rect');
    rect.setAttribute('x',x);
    rect.setAttribute('y',y);
    rect.setAttribute('width',width);
    rect.setAttribute('height',height);
    rect.setAttribute('fill','yellow');
    svg.appendChild(rect);
}

var el = document.getElementById('EF-VR1');
el.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    coverRect(el);
}, false);
```

The rect is correctly displayed but not on the rect on which I pass the mouse over. Moreover I would like to alter the alpha of the rect in order to show what is below, and to pass the click being intercepted by the underlaying rect.

Comment: set the opacity to change the alpha. As to the positioning please create a [mcve]

Comment: Opacity does work, thanks. As for the example, I am no SVG expert, today it is the first time I have to do with one. I was given an SVG file by the client and I need to work on it, it was not my production. If you give me your email address I may send it to you as the information is reserved and I cannot share it publicly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed the issue by changing the cursor.